# How to update filename with date in current time

Tags: shell, date, command, filenames

I am trying to launch a stdbuf which be able to make a new log each day using this order in the shell:

```
stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 /.../my_dir/watchdog_foo >> /.../my_dir/log_foo_`date '+%F'` &
```

With this, I would want to have:

```
log_foo_2017-11-28
log_foo_2017-11-29
...
```

For testing, I have launched this other order:

```
stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 /.../my_dir/watchdog_foo >> /.../my_dir/log_foo_`date '+%R'` &
```

trying to see if a log was created each minute, but it didn't happened. The log had been writing on the same file all this time whileas what I hopped was:

```
log_foo_18:05
log_foo_18:06
...
```

How could I modify this command for achieve my purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you launch this command, the `date +%R` is expanded by your shell to the current time. After that, it is not updated again, so your log will be redirected to the same file. To get your desired behavior, you'd need to re-launch your script every day (to get the updated date). You could use a tool like `cron` to run the script every night at midnight to kill the previous process and re-run with the new date.

You could also look into leveraging a tool like [`logrotate`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate).